# ThreadingTCPServer won't exit when client connected

Tags: python, tcp, socketserver

I am running a simple echo socketserver and whenever there is a client connected, ctrl C doesn't exit/terminate the server. Instead it "hangs" until client disconnects from the socket. I have read somewhere that this is due to there being a thread alive even after the main thread has been terminated. How do I fix this issue?

Python code (excuse some of the indents, it did not copy paste well):

```
import SocketServer
from SocketServer import TCPServer, ThreadingMixIn, StreamRequestHandler
import sys
import time
import socket
import os

class ThreadingTCPServer(ThreadingMixIn, TCPServer):
     pass

class RequestHandler(StreamRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        print str(self.client_address) + 'connected'
        data = "foo"
        while data != "":
            try:
                data = self.rfile.readline().rstrip('\n')
            except:
                self.request.close()
                print 'Socket Error'
                break
                print data
            try:
                self.wfile.write("OK\n")
            except socket.error:
                data = ""
        print 'Handler Exiting'
        self.request.close()

    def finish(self):
        print 'Client ' + str(self.client_address) + ' Disconnected'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PORT = 80
    print 'Starting Server on port: ' + str(PORT)
    ThreadingTCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True
    server = ThreadingTCPServer(("", PORT), RequestHandler)
    try:    
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "\nServer Terminated"
        server.shutdown()
        sys.exit()
```

All responses are appreciated, thank you for your time!

Comment: it's written in the spec that you can't call `shutdown()` from the same thread that runs `serve_forever()`... that's because `shudown()` sets a flag that `server_forever()` uses. Look at the code, it's not hard to understand https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/socketserver.py A solution is to run `serve_forever()` in its own thread and then `shutdown()`  will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this at the start of your program:

```
import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
```

What it does is to restore the default before for Ctrl-C (SIGINT), which is to terminate the program immediately.

Comment: I feel as though I could kiss you! I was struggling forever with this issue.